# Robustness and Sensitivity of Naive Bayes to Irrelevant Features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes-classifier, features

I understand that one of the strengths of Naive Bayes is its robustness to irrelevant features. However, it's also important to note that it can be sensitive to the presence of irrelevant features, which can sometimes affect its performance. Can someone help explain how these two points can coexist? Any assistance would be appreciated.

I tried with Chatgpt and gave me the next response :

> the sensitivity to the presence of irrelevant features refers to the fact that Naive Bayes can still be influenced by these features, especially if they are strongly correlated with the target variable. So, while Naive Bayes is generally robust, it can still be affected by irrelevant features if they are not truly independent of the target variable.

Actually, I could understand how they are irrelevant and in the same time strongly correlated with the target?